# Optimal value of the semi-definite programming and slater's condition

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, semidefinite-programming

I am trying to get started with semi-definite programming following Boyd's notes. I was trying to solve a problem as below:

I have an SDP of the following primal form:

$\operatorname{min}\langle C, X\rangle$

subject to $\left\langle A_{i}, X\right\rangle= b_{i}, \quad i=1,2$

$X$ is positive-semidefinite
with
$$
C=\left[\begin{array}{ll}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{array}\right], A_{1}=\left[\begin{array}{ll}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{array}\right], A_{2}=\left[\begin{array}{ll}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right], b_{1}=1, b_{2}=0
$$

1. How can I check if this satisfies slater's condition?
2. How to find the optimal value and optimal X corresponding to this problem?

**My attempt:**
Assume $$
X=\left[\begin{array}{ll}
a & b \\
b & c
\end{array}\right]$$

$\left\langle A_{1}, X\right\rangle= 1$ implies $a=1$
$\left\langle A_{2}, X\right\rangle= 0$ implies $c=0$

Now the determinant is $-b^{2}$, hence positive-semidefiniteness implies $b=0$

But for strict feasibility, we need X to be positive-definite, which is impossible in this case. Hence slater's condition is not satisfied.

Comment: What have you tried? What happens if you try to use the definition of slater's condition?

Comment: @supinf , Slater's condition says that there exists a strictly feasible point. If I assume X =[a b; b c]  as the symmetric positive semidefinite matrix, slater's condition implies a=1 and c=0. And b=0 from positive-semidefiniteness as determinant of X is -b^2.

Comment: ok but what exactly is a strictly feasible point (as opposed to being simply feasible)?

Comment: @supinf ,   A strictly feasible point is a feasible point within the interior of the domain (i.e., excludes boundary). So, X should be positive definite instead of just positive semi-definite . But since determinant is -b^2 , which is never positive, I think there is no strictly feasible point.

Comment: @supinf, Furthermore now the optimal value is 2b=2 x 0 =0 and X=[1 0; 0 0] is the optimal point. Could you please let me kmow if I am right?

Comment: sounds right to me.